# Fibonacci coding

Tags: information-theory, universal-code

Can anybody suggest a good book/paper/website/background reading about universal codes for integers and especially Fibonacci code (in the sense of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_code)? Thanks!

**Edit:** Thanks for the answers and the useful links so far! I am sorry if I have not made myself completely clear: I am not asking about code (as in writing a program) to generate or compute Fibonacci numbers, but about a particular code (as in encoding, or compressing, data) that makes use of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Maybe you need code for some student project or task?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate what your end goal is (if you have one besides just learning about this). The wikipedia article you cited seems to have a good overview, although the technical aspects are slightly over my head. Definitely look into information theory, maybe Huffman coding.

Answer (score 3):

One paper found with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) :

- [Data compression](http://radio-1.ee.dal.ca/~ilow/4540/readings/DataCompression.pdf) (DA Lelewer, DS Hirschberg - ACM Computing Surveys (CSUR), 1987)

I'm not so familiar with the subject but the article seems to be pretty decent by a brief looking.

Answer (score 2):

[Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html) has a chapter on codes. It has a free pdf version, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I find MIT's online lectures to be a good resource generally.  And they address Fibonacci algorithms in some detail:  http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-two/

Relevant segments of the video:

[17:49] Algorithms for computing Fibonacci numbers (FBs).
[19:04] Naive recursive algorithm (exponential time) for computing FBs.
[22:45] Bottom-up algorithm for computing FBs.
[24:25] Naive recursive squaring algorithm for FBs (doesn’t work because of floating point rounding errors).
[27:00] Recursive squaring algorithm for FBs.